# How to write python unittest for column name is a string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-unittest

I am not if this is right to but, I have this so far and I am trying to write unittest for this.

```
 def ValidateInputs(self, class_column_name,):

    class_column_name_ok = type(class_column_name) is str
    if not class_column_name_ok:
        raise(TypeError("Argument class_column_name must be a string type"))
```

I did this for this unittest but again with not having enough knowledge I am not sure. Any help will be much appreciated

```
def testClassColumnName(self):
    self.assertTrue(type(class_column_name), "str")
```

Comment: you can check `isinstance(class_column_name, str)` to see whether the type of the column name is a string or not. So, you could reduce your condition to `if not isinstance(class_column_name, str)`

Comment: @Slayer so, In unit test I should just do "self.assertTrue(isinstance(class_column_name, str))" sorry for stupid question, I am just not really good at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what you do with these values, I can't say 100%. I'll assume you bind them to the class, then provide the unittests I'd write.

Application code:

```
class MyClass(object):
    """This is my object, this is what it does"""

    def validate_inputs(self, merge_columns, class_column_name):
        """some handy docstring"""
        if not isinstance(class_column_name, str):
            raise TypeError('Argument class_column_name must be a string, supplied {0}'.format(type(class_column_name))
        self.class_column_name = class_column_name
```

unittests (using unittest form the stdlib):

```
import unittest

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.myclass = MyClass() # cheap way to always have a 'clean class' for testing

    def test_validate_input_type_string(self):
        """Happy path test when input is correct, and everything works"""
        self.myclass.validate_input(merge_columns='some-columns', class_column_name='some_column_name')

        self.assertEqual(True, isinstance(self.myclass.class_column_name, str))

    def test_validate_input_raises_typerror(self):
        """We raise TypeError if input != string"""
        self.assertRaises(TypeError,
                          self.myclass.validate_input,
                          merge_columns=1234,
                          class_column_name=4321)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

General tips for unittesting:

A) Use self.assertEqual(A, B) -> the output on failure will give you some clue on why it failed. Using something like self.assertTrue normaly just outputs an error message like "False is not True"; which is, while 100% accurate, not very useful.

B) Supplying all positional args as key-word args -> makes reading the test later easier.

C) One assert per test case (two at the very most) -> more than this tends to get your test code too complex. Test should be so simple that anyone (even that intern that was just hired from a 3 month coding bootcamp) can figure them out. It's really painful to rewrite a hole test suite (or spend hours updating test code) b/c of a 10 minute update to application code.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs. Question, what does ".format(type(class_column_name))" do? I am kinda confused there.

Comment: I'm just adding the type that was supplied to the error message. The ' {}'.format() way is the new style, doing '%s' % thing is the old way. Checkout [this](https://pyformat.info/) link for more info.